# Functional programming in Python: find smallest odd number in list

Tags: python, algorithm, functional-programming

How can I find the smallest odd number in a list of integers, if the problem statement says that I can't use ***for*** and ***if***?

Comment: Do you understand what functional programming is? Why constrain yourself from using for or if statements?

Comment: odds = [i for i in lints if (i%2) == 1]; min(odds)

Comment: @Gary02127 - you used an `if`

Comment: `min(filter((2).__rmod__, l))`

Comment: @PatrickArtner - I figured I could get away with it since it's nested... :)

Comment: I can't use if and for because it's one of the terms of the problem. I added a clarification to the original post.

Comment: filter is self implemented with `if` and Lambda also makes use of compare. Well, in case you don't know , there also also algorithms which can sort without even comparing things. Try to look how those work.

Comment: You can circumvent the rules with `while`s - see answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `min`:

```
s = [4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 1]
smallest_odd = min(filter(lambda x:x%2 != 0, s))
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why should anyone consider using `for` or `if`?

```
min(numbers, key=lambda n: (n&1==0, n))
```

Comment: Because it's significantly faster? Comparing `min(num for num in numbers if num % 2 == 0)` to your solution, you'll see a two/three-fold improvement in speed. This is still true even if we define the key function outside of the timing environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ints = [2,6,8,4,6  ]

srt = sorted(ints)

while len(srt) > 0 and not srt[0] % 2:
    srt = srt[1:]

s = None
while len(srt):
    s = srt[0]
    srt=[]

print(s)
```

to circumvent the rules.  You sort the list, discard any even values from front.

The resulting list is either empty or has the value at front.

The second while is only entered if the list contains elements, and the list is reset to empty (which is false and will not renter the while).

It will print "None" or the lowest not even number.